# Do the natives use "Salute"?

Tags: verbs

I might be wrong but I think the verb "**to salute**" is quite rare now and people don't use it, but might I be mistaking?

Comment: I think that this verb is limited pretty much to the military.  Therefore any use of this verb will have a martial feel to it. You salute the flag, you might ironically salute your friend or an enemy (perhaps with just your middle finger.)  Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the U.S., the verb "to salute" is quite common.

- The military uses it.
- The police use it.
- The Boy Scouts and Girl Scouts use it.
- All Americans salute the flag when they place their hands over their hearts.
- Movies, books, and especially music are frequently written to salute a (usually dead) person or (usually noble) cause.

Frankly, I don't believe the verb's commonality has changed at all.